# combining text in multiple runs in MS Word XML

Tags: xslt, ms-word

I have a formatted word XML document and I need PHP to insert data into that document prior to outputting the document to the user. But the XML is cluttered and the text is split up into serveral runs. 
Is there a way to merge the runs so that the text is readable in the XML again, and i can replace text in de the XML document?

Here is a portion of the XML with the split text example:

```
<w:r w:rsidR="00651D23">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
<w:sz w:val="20"/>
<w:szCs w:val="20"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>Broke</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00433EDE" w:rsidRPr="002A1163">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
<w:sz w:val="20"/>
<w:szCs w:val="20"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>n part of text</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
```

ideally it would become something like this:

```
<w:r w:rsidR="00651D23">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
<w:sz w:val="20"/>
<w:szCs w:val="20"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>Broken part of text</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
```

Comment: How would one know where the text begins and ends? IOW, post a minimal, but **complete** example.

Comment: Text inside `w:p` split into several `w:r` is the normal, expected behaviour of OOXML documents. Runs might have different properties (inside `w:rPr`) - what run properties would you assign to the merged run? Why does inserting data with PHP require merging the runs in the first place?

Comment: @michael.hor: I am not really familiar with the word XML structure, this is my first attempt to do this.The document is large an requires very specific mark-up and needs to be served online to users. It seemed easier to me to take the XML document, insert the data in the document, and stream it to the browser so the user can save it to their computer, in stead of building the entire document with php including all the data and mark-up.
The merging would be welcome so that the document becomes better readable for in order to find the insertion points

Answer (score 0):

See [VariablePrepare](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/datastorage/migration/VariablePrepare.java) for how to do it in Java.  Feel free to copy the approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in 3rd party library which deals with such issues for you (but requires Java) check out [Templater](http://templater.info/demo).

Disclaimer: I'm the author.